# Is it possible to check the value of a control using a string in VBA(excel)

Tags: vba, excel

I've been googling for 3 and a half hours straight, found multiple solutions, but none of them works for me. I'm trying to loop through all of the checkboxes and mark the columns green for the ones that are checked. Here's my code:

```
Dim Kontrola As Shape

For Each Kontrola In ActiveSheet.Shapes

Debug.Print "CheckBox" + Right(Kontrola.Name, 2)


If Len(Kontrola.Name) = 10 Then
    If Sheet1.OLEObjects("CheckBox" + Right(Kontrola.Name, 2)).Value = True Then
         Sheet1.Rows(2).Interior.Color = vbGreen
         Sheet1.CheckBox10.Interior.Color = vbGreen
    End If
End If

If Len(Kontrola.Name) < 10 Then
    Debug.Print Right(Kontrola.Name, 1)
End If
```

Next Kontrola

Comment: Do you mean & rather than + btw? Also, what do you mean by none of them works? What happens? Any error messages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe something like this (Sheet.CheckBoxes contains only the Form Controls CheckBoxes)

```
For Each cb In Sheet1.CheckBoxes
    cb.TopLeftCell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = IIf(cb = 1, vbGreen, xlNone)
Next
```

You probably don't need VBA for this, as you can just link the CheckBox to Excel cell, and use Conditional Formatting to make cells green based on the linked cell value.

---

I would recommend using Form Controls instead, as ActiveX controls can be disabled based on the user preferences, but here is sample with 
ActiveX Checkboxes:

```
For Each o In Sheet1.OLEObjects
    If TypeOf o.Object Is MSForms.CheckBox Then
         o.TopLeftCell.EntireRow.Interior.Color = IIf(o.Object.Value, vbGreen, xlNone)
    End If
Next
```

Comment: thanks worked perfectly! i'm just practicing vba so i'm intentionally trying to do it the hard way